# While PHP não ultrapassar contagem

Tags: php, html

Como faço pro while identificar que vai ultrapassar a contagem definida no formulário e pausar antes?

FORMULARIO:

```
<form method="get" action="exercico04.php">
Inicio: <input type="number" name="inicio" value="1" max="100" min="1"/><br/>
Final: <input type="number" name="final" value="1" max="100" min="1"/><br/>
Incremento:
<select name="incremento">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Contar" class="botao"/>
```

PHP:

```
$inis = isset($_GET["inicio"])?$_GET["inicio"]:0;
    $finis = isset($_GET["final"])?$_GET["final"]:0;
    $incris = isset($_GET["incremento"])?$_GET["incremento"]:0;

    if($inis < $finis){
        echo $inis . "  ";
        while($inis < $finis) {
            $inis+=$incris;
        echo $inis."  ";
    }
}else if($inis > $finis){
    echo $inis . ",";
    while($inis > $finis) {
            $inis-=$incris;
        echo $inis ."  ";
    }
}
```

No caso, por exemplo, se eu escolher INICIO 7, FINAL 45 e INCREMENTO 4, ele vai contar assim: 7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43 47

Só que no caso, quero que ele pare antes de chegar no 45, que seria no caso no 43. Como faço isso?

Comment: Final é menor que inicio?

Comment: Everson. O Código PHP todo não quer aparecer ali, mas seria assim:  $inis = isset($_GET["inicio"])?$_GET["inicio"]:0;
 $finis = isset($_GET["final"])?$_GET["final"]:0;
 $incris = isset($_GET["incremento"])?$_GET["incremento"]:0;
 
 if($inis < $finis){
  echo $inis . "  ";
  while($inis < $finis) {
   $inis+=$incris;
  echo $inis."  ";
 }
} else if($inis > $finis){
 echo $inis . ",";
 while($inis > $finis) {
   $inis-=$incris;
  echo $inis ."  ";
 }
}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existem alguns erros em seu código, como por exemplo `if($inis  $finis)`, essa condição é inválida, outro erro é a condição do `while` onde `while($inis > $finis) {` se inicio esta recebendo 7 e fim 45 nunca entrará no laço, por último, você esta decrementando o inicio e não incrementando, veja um exemplo com as correçoes:

```
$inis = isset($_GET["inicio"])?$_GET["inicio"]:0;
$finis = isset($_GET["final"])?$_GET["final"]:0;
$incris = isset($_GET["incremento"])?$_GET["incremento"]:0;

if($inis != 0 && $finis != 0 && $incris != 0){
   /*Verifica se o usuário não inverteu inicio e fim, se sim troca
   *Por exemplo: $inis = 45; $finis = 7;
   *Neste caso será necessário inverter as variáveis
   *
   */
   if($inis > $finis){
      $aux = $inis;//armazena o valor original de $inis na variável $aux = 45
      $inis = $finis; //$inis = 7
      $finis = $aux; //Agora recebe valor de $aux, ou seja $finis = 45
      //Depois dessa troca os valores de início e fim estarão corretos
      //$inis = 7;
      //$finis = 45;
   }

   while($inis < $finis) {
     echo $inis ."  "; // imprime o primeiro valor
     $inis+=$incris;//incrementa
     if($inis > $finis) {//se após incrementar $inis > $finis
       $inis = $finis;
       echo $inis ."  ";//imprime o $finis
     }  
   }
}
```

[EXEMPLO NO IDEONE](https://ideone.com/3Lk9wv)

Comment: Estava mal formatado, agora está OK

Comment: colocando mais uma verificação dentro do laço WHILE você pode controlar se a variável está chegando perto do valor que você deseja parar; if( $inis + $incris> 45 ) { break; } (você pode substituir o 45 por uma variavel

Comment: @Everson sim é uma opção

Comment: @LucasCarvalho veja a edição ao invés de repetir o `while`, você pode checar as variáveis e fazer a troca.

Comment: Não sei se viu minha edição, abfurlan, mas agora la está com o código que fiz. Não entendi muito bem duas partes, a parte pra checar se é diferente de 0 e a criação da variável $aux, poderia explicar?

Comment: Verifica se é `!= 0` pois o `$inis = isset($_GET["inicio"])?$_GET["inicio"]:0;` é um `if` condicional que atribui zero a variável caso não exista no `GET` correto? imagino que se não foi informado por algum motivo o código não será executado, quanto a variável `$aux`, serve somente para efetuar a troca, caso `$inis > $finis`, veja minha  edição com os comentários.

Comment: Obrigado a todos! Principalmente a você, abfurlan!

Answer (score 4):

Usando um for

```
if($_GET["inicio"] != 0 && $_GET["final"] != 0 && $_GET["incremento"] != 0){
   $inis=$_GET["inicio"];
   $finis=$_GET["final"];
   $incris=$_GET["incremento"];


    for ($x = $inis; $x < $finis; $x=($x+$incris)) {

        if ($x == $inis){
            echo $inis ."  ";
        }else{
            $inis+=$incris;
            echo $inis ."  ";
        }
    }
}
```

> A estrutura de repetição FOR é utilizada para se executar um conjunto de comandos por um número definido de vezes. Para esse operador, são passados uma situação inicial, uma condição e uma ação a ser executada a cada repetição.
>
> Em geral informamos uma variável que serve como contador de repetições, com seu valor inicial, uma condição a ser atendida para que cada repetição seja executada e um incremento ao contador.

**Sintaxe do operador FOR**

```
for(valor inicial; condição; incremento)
{
  //comandos
}
```

**Aproveitando a fabulosa ideia do nosso amigo abfurlan**

"Verifica se o usuário não inverteu inicio e fim, se sim troca"

Ficaria assim:

```
$inis = isset($_GET["inicio"])?$_GET["inicio"]:0;
$finis = isset($_GET["final"])?$_GET["final"]:0;
$incris = isset($_GET["incremento"])?$_GET["incremento"]:0;

if($inis != 0 && $finis != 0 && $incris != 0){
   if($inis > $finis){
      $aux = $inis;
      $inis = $finis;
      $finis = $aux;

   }

        for ($x = $inis; $x < $finis; $x=($x+$incris)) {

            if ($x == $inis){
                echo $inis ."  ";
            }else{
                $inis+=$incris;
                echo $inis ."  ";
            }
        }  

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Uma solução mais simples para fazer o que quer é utilizar o [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php), que é nativo.

Isso é tudo que precisa:

```
// Trata o input:
$inicio = $_GET['inicio'] ?? 0;
$inicio = is_numeric($inicio) ? $inicio : 0;

$final = $_GET['final'] ?? 0;
$final = is_numeric($final) ? $final : 0;

$incremento = $_GET['incremento'] ?? 1;
$incremento = is_numeric($incremento) && $incremento != 0 ? $incremento : 1;

// Faz o mesmo que o `while`:
echo implode(' ', range($inicio, $final, $incremento));
```

**[Teste isto aqui.](https://3v4l.org/GZDsq)**

---

O `range()` irá fazer com que vá de `$inicio` até o `$fim`, se definido um `$incremento` ele irá "pular", ele não pode ser `0`. Ele retorna uma `array`, por exemplo um `var_export(range(7, 45, 4));` resulta em:

```
array ( 0 => 7, 1 => 11, 2 => 15, 3 => 19, 4 => 23, 5 => 27, 6 => 31, 7 => 35, 8 => 39, 9 => 43 )
```

Dessa forma temos, `7` até `43`, como deseja.

O `implode()` é feito para juntar os valores, dessa forma juntamos tudo com um (espaço) entre eles.

Dessa forma o resultado que temos de `implode(' ', range(7, 45, 4))` é justamente:

```
7 11 15 19 23 27 31 35 39 43
```

Veja a [documentação do `implode()` clicando aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php) e a [documentação do `range()` aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.range.php). Vale lembrar que o `range()` também serve para letras, um `range('a', 'z')` resultará no alfabeto. ;)